# Allowing one way Iframe interaction

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

Is there any way to only allow parent to control iframe, but no iframe to control parent in html/javascript?

I am making a sandbox mode for my website, and I want people to be able to make their own javascript, but I don't want to allow them to change my site. On the other hand, I might want to add scripts that change things in the iframe.

I see that in newer browsers there is a way to sandbox the iframe - [sandbox](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_iframe_sandbox.asp).

My question is, has anyone come up with a way to make it work unilaterally?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iFrame isolation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2672484/iframe-isolation)

Answer (score 1):

This was already answered there :

[iFrame isolation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2672484/iframe-isolation)

The answer is apparently **no, there is no way to do that**...

In the comment, somebody says something about security and having your IFrame in a different domain than the parent. Maybe you can try if your browser support this feature.

Comment: I don't think this is completely correct - using http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_iframe_sandbox.asp - you can block both sides - so I was wondering if I can do it unilaterally - anyway, so this answer is outdated it seems to me?

Comment: Yes sandbox is new to HTML5. Sadly this is not what you are looking for. The only solution I see would be to write a plugin to manage the isolation yourself.