# How can I isolate parts in a web page so that one part would not affect other parts

Tags: error-handling, runtime-error, integration, html, defensive-programming

I am managing a project in which development is done by multiple developers working on different parts of a web page. We are facing integration issues when combining parts of a web page due to side effects.

If a web part has an error, is poorly written, or is blocked by a web filter, that affects rendering of other parts of the web page.

Is there a way to cleanly compartmentalize a web page?

My research pointed out only share point web parts but not an approach or framework for this exact problem. [IFrame Isolation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2672484/iframe-isolation) is related but that solution is akin to placing a square peg in a round hole.

Comment: You can create "vanilla" custom elements, use iframe isolation, create components with any JS frameworks... so many solutions!

Comment: @Supersharp Thq but I am looking for a robust solution which will isolate parts of the web page. These parts should not have any side-effects.I looked at iframe but it doesn't serve the purpose, I have edited my question to include the SO link though.

Comment: I don't see in your update why you cannot use iframe, anyway you can try to use components like custom elements https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/customelements

Comment: 1. Because iframe execute in a single thread. 2. Iframe make it difficult to design responsive.

Answer (score 0):

> If a web part has an error or is poorly written or if it is blocked by a web filtering, that affects rendering of other parts of the web page.

Use try/catch blocks:

```js
window.addEventListener("error", function(e){return false;}, true);
try{angular.run();}
catch(e){console.log(e.toString() )};
$("body").append("<div>Hi</div>");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

or lazy loading:

```js
void(function foo()
  {
  /* get head element */
  var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];

  /* create script element */
  var jQueryJS = document.createElement("script");


  /* define script src attribute to lazy load */
  jQueryJS.src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js";

  /* append script */
  head.appendChild(jQueryJS);


  /* call tests after jQuery loads */
  jQueryJS.onload = function () 
    {
    $("body").append("<h1>Hi</h1>");
    }
  }() 
);
```

Other approaches include:

- HTML5 sandbox/CSP-enabled security architecture
- TreeHouse: web workers sandbox architecture
- JSand: Secure ECMAScript(SES)-enabled sandbox architecture
- ADSafe: virtual iframes

**References**

- [The Web Security Model (pdf) - Philippe De  Ryck](https://handouts.secappdev.org/handouts/2014/Philippe%20De%20Ryck/WebSecurityModel.pdf)
- [Web security: Securing Untrusted Web Content in Browsers](http://www.slideshare.net/phungphu/w-38954098)
- [Application Security 
  Trends and Challenges (pdf)](https://handouts.secappdev.org/handouts/2015/Wouter%20Joosen/SecAppDev2015OpeningWJ.pdf)
- [Sandboxing Javascript - Lieven Desmet and Nick Nikiforakis (pdf)](https://www.owasp.org/images/d/d8/Sandboxing-Javascript_-_Lieven_Desmet%2BNick_Nikiforakis.pdf)
- [Server-Side Template Injection: RCE for the modern webapp (pdf)](https://www.blackhat.com/docs/us-15/materials/us-15-Kettle-Server-Side-Template-Injection-RCE-For-The-Modern-Web-App-wp.pdf)