# How to include 3rd party HTML snippet in isolation on web page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, shadow-dom

I have to make a call from my Web app to a 3rd party web service, which will will return an HTML document, that i want to in-turn include on my page; basically consuming syndicated self-contained promotional "chunks" of html (which include the CSS to layout/style them as the syndicator intended).

Is there a way to do this and isolate the HTML without using iframes (since its hard to tell how to size the iframe)? I'd like to ensure that 1) the incoming CSS/JS doesn't impact the rest of the page, and vice versa - i don't want the greater page's styles to impact the view of the promo content.

Is there something that can be done with Shadowdom/shadowdom-polyfills? or Web components?

It seems like the Twitter/Instagram are able to do do this someone?

Comment: Somewhat related: [iFrame isolation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2672484/691711) especially with a sandbox attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [Shadow DOM](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-components/shadowdom) you can isolate CSS.

```js
promo.attachShadow( { mode: 'open' } )
     .innerHTML = `
        <style> 
          div { color: red ; }
        </style>
        <div>Isolated CSS style</div>`
```

```html
<div id="promo"></div>
```

Unfortunately you won't be able to isolate Javascript.

For Javascript isolation, the only way is `<iframe>` with the `sandbox` attribute as stated by @zero298.

Answer (score 2):

You can make it in web components **import** way:

Reference your HTML resource:

```
<link rel="import" href="http://example.com/elements.html">
```

Access and use imported content through JavaScript

```
var content = document.querySelector('link[rel="import"]').import;
```

Let's say **warnings.html** contains:

```
<div class="warning">
    <style>
        h3 {
            color: red !important;
        }
    </style>
    <h3>Warning!</h3>
    <p>This page is under construction</p>
</div>
<div class="outdated">
    <h3>Heads up!</h3>
    <p>This content may be out of date</p>
</div>
```

Importers can grab a specific portion of this document and clone it into their page:

```
<head>
    <link rel="import" href="warnings.html">
</head>
<body>
    ...
    <script>
        var link = document.querySelector('link[rel="import"]');
        var content = link.import;

        // Grab DOM from warning.html's document.
        var el = content.querySelector('.warning');
        document.body.appendChild(el.cloneNode(true));
    </script>
</body>
```

Tip: Don't forget that if the HTML origin is external, the resource server must be cors-enabled.

Example extracted from [here](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/imports/)

Comment: I recommend adding relevant snippets of the blog entry you linked so that (for whatever reason) if the post goes down, future readers can still reference the information they need.

Comment: In your warnings example, if I have an H3 on the container page (not the imported), wouldn’t i risk  turning the h3s all red? And or if the container page had a ‘body h3 { color: blue }’ css rule, wouldn’t the objected warning be blue (and not red)? I’m struggling to see the automatic style isolation.

Comment: @empire29. Yes, you must put them in a Shadow DOM to isolate imported styles

Comment: Thanks for clearing it up - both are very helpful answers!

Comment: @empire29 yes they are complementary